# Wrong result when trying to get nth min element from a unsorted array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to get the nTh minimum element from an unsorted array of ints. This is what I have tried so far:

```
private static int nthMin(int[] array, int m) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = array.length - 1;
    int index = 0;
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] < array[index]) {
            newArray[start] = array[i];
            start++;
        } else {
            newArray[end] = array[i];
            end--;
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }
    if(m > start) {
        return nthMin(Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, start + 1, newArray.length), m - start);
    } else if(m < start) {
        return nthMin(Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, 0, start), m);
    } else {
        return array[start];
    }
}
```

And I'm calling this method using:

```
int[] array = {10, 2, 5, 6, 11, 3, 15};
System.out.println(nthMin(array, 2));
```

If a try to print the `newArray`, I get:

```
[2, 5, 6, 3, 15, 11, 10]
```

Which in my opinion is correct. However, when I run the entire code, I get the second min as `2` but it should be `3`. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186472/discussion-on-question-by-oleg-caralanski-wrong-result-when-trying-to-get-nth-mi).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to change not to much. Now the for loop moves the min and the max to start/end of the newArray and than it moves on to another call of the method.

```
private static int nthMin(int[] array, int m) {
    if ((array.length == 1) && (m == 1)) {
        return array[0];
    }

    int start = 0;
    int end = array.length - 1;
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];

    if (array[0] < array[1]) {
        newArray[start] = array[0];
        newArray[end] = array[1];
    } else {
        newArray[start] = array[1];
        newArray[end] = array[0];
    }

    start++;
    end--;
    for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < newArray[0]) {
            newArray[start] = newArray[0];
            newArray[0] = array[i];
            start++;
        } else if (array[i] > newArray[array.length - 1]) {
            newArray[end] = newArray[array.length - 1];
            newArray[array.length - 1] = array[i];
            end--;
        } else {
            newArray[start] = array[i];
            start++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }

    if (m == 1) {
        return newArray[0];
    }
    return nthMin(Arrays.copyOfRange(newArray, 1, newArray.length), m - 1);
}
```

Comment: Waw, it works using recursive call. Thanks! Can you please explain a little what have you done? Thanks! Vote-ud up.

Comment: OK. I start with handling the simple case of an 1-element-array. Next is to initialize a newArray. Since you wanted to get min and max I put the first to elements of the array at start and end of newArray (after checking which one is the smaller one). In the for-loop I check if the next element of the original array is smaller than the first in newArray or bigger than the last in newArray or else. I put this element at an appropriate place. After the loop the min and max should be at first and last place. Then I check for the n-1th min in the subarray starting at the second element.

Comment: You could make it easier if you don't look for the max-element. You don't need it. Have in mind that you may want to look for the nth-min Element in an array with (n+1) elements.

Answer (score 2):

> // A function to implement **recursive bubble sort**

```
static void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    // Base case 
    if (n == 1) 
        return; 

    // One pass of bubble sort. After 
    // this pass, the largest element 
    // is moved (or bubbled) to end. 
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) 
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) 
        { 
            // swap arr[i], arr[i+1] 
            int temp = arr[i]; 
            arr[i] = arr[i+1]; 
            arr[i+1] = temp; 
        } 

    // Largest element is fixed, 
    // recur for remaining array 
    bubbleSort(arr, n-1); 
}
```

> // Driver Method

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int arr[] = {2, 5, 6, 3, 15, 11, 10}; 

    bubbleSort(arr, arr.length); 
      System.out.println("Enter nth Min element you want");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nth = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Nth Min element in your array is: "+arr[nth-1]);

}
```

**Edit 1**: *I read the comment and found that you cannot use arrays.sort(), my suggestion is to use bubble sort then to sort, cant you use bubble sort or it is also not allowed?*

**Edit 2:** Done by [recursive bubble](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-bubble-sort/) sort, wait.

Comment: Thanks @CommonMan for your response. Unfortunately I only am allowed to use a recursive call.

Comment: wait , i am doing your recursive part.

Comment: can we use recursive bubble sort?? @OlegCaralanski

Comment: No. I know that solution but is not allowed in my use-case.

Comment: It's another elegant way. Thanks! Voted-up.

Comment: This code is copy + pasted from this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-bubble-sort/

Comment: Ohh..It is modified also, pay attention sir, moreover see edit 2 ref is there, huh..just blatantly downvoting..@Lino

Comment: @CommonMan *see edit 2 ref is there* well after I posted my comment. Also your "changes" were just changing the c# code to java, which still counts as copy paste IMHO

Comment: @Lino, see the main program, is it copied?? If you say changing the language is still a copy-paste, then every answer is copy paste of yours as they some what are similar to some answer previously. Anyways, thanks for pointing out. I dont have any grudge on you, good day.

Comment: @CommonMan Well you even copy + pasted the comments from the author, so this seems like a no-effort answer. When diff-checking your answer vs the one from the blog post, the only difference is the `swap` method, which doesn't exist in java. So yeah, I still think this is a copy paste of the main logic this question is about. Also OP would like to improve **his** code and not use another solution

Comment: @Lino, Thanks man ! I appreciate your suggestions and i will keep it in mind you are better that you at-least pointed the mistake whereas others will just run away. BTW i did not used sawp function whereas i implemented by bubble recursion, dont know what you are on saying.

Comment: @CommonMan I, like many here, are just trying to make this website a better place, and everyone makes mistakes. It doesn't matter anymore you have running code, so that counts

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the QuickSelect Algorithem
[Github unnikked/QuickSelect.java](https://gist.github.com/unnikked/14c19ba13f6a4bfd00a3)

you can find here an iterative and recursive solutions to make your code better.

Comment: Thank you for that resource. I'll take a look.

Comment: I just tried the code and I get the same result as I get using my code. `2` instead of `3`.